# \n as well as <br> for new line in JavaScript alert not working

Tags: javascript, alert

I am using a JavaScript alert (a little modified though). This alert has a title field and a content field. In my content field I want to display some text in new line, but neither `\n` nor `<br>` is working. See the image to check the output of the given code.

```
new Attention.Alert({
                title: 'School',
                content: 'Date - '+v_date+'\n School Name - '+ school_name + "\n School City - " + school_city + " "
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are using a html popup kind of alert so instead of using `\n` try `<br>`

Comment: I have tried <br> as well but that too doesn't work @MayankPandeyz

Comment: You are breaking lines in correct way by using `\n`. You just have to add one `css` for the content. Just add `white-space: pre-line;` for the content in alert.

Comment: sorry @AsfanShaikh it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `CSS` `white-space: pre-line;` for popup content.

**Here is working Example.**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var v_date = '04/11/2019';
    var school_name = 'School Name';
    var school_city = 'School City';
    new Attention.Alert({
        title: 'This is a Title',
        content: 'Date - '+v_date+'\n School Name - '+school_name+'\n School City - '+school_city
    });
  });
});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
 background-color: #d1d8de;
 padding: 20px;    
}
.attention-component .inner-container p{
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://janmarkuslanger.github.io/attention.js/dist/attention.js"></script>
<link href="https://janmarkuslanger.github.io/attention.js/dist/attention.css" rel="stylesheet">
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou So much buddy It finally worked for me. I was adding the css in the attention.css and it was not working but when I added the css as internal it started working. Thankyou so much.